# issue with Intellij : local branches don't show

Tags: intellij-idea

In a terminal I have switched to a local branch on my project.
[image]
When I open Intellij, it still points to Master. And when I open the git branch panel (bottom right of Intellij), I only see Remote branches.

[image]

Do you know how to switch to the same local branch in Intellij, and how to display the local branches too?

Thank you.

Comment: Please post the screenshot with more information, not just a cut (which may cut some important information.)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Like Dmitrii already said. There is a setting in Inttelij that enabled it for me. It's called "Execute Branch Operations on All Roots".

[Setting in Intellij to enable Git Operations on all Repositories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDL27.png)

Answer (score 0):

> it still points to Master

How do you know? When you are on some branch, IntelliJ will at least show the branch itself in the popup, with a HEAD mark and ability to rename.

It looks like branches popup is attached to some other repo. Make sure the mapping in Settings | Version Control is correct and check the IDE logs for possible errors.